# Error con MBCircularProgressBar en Swift

Tags: swift

Estoy representando unos determinados datos los cuales los recojo de una base de datos MySQL.

Dichos datos quiero representarlos en unos gauges "MBCircularProgressBar" pero me salta un error.

Cuando asigno las variables a dichos Outlets de los gauges me salta el error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Interlight_App/ViewController.swift, line 139

*Lo raro viene ahora*, cuando pongo dicha pantalla del storyboard como `as initial view controller` se me representan los datos perfectamente, pero, cuando elijo mi pantalla principal de "inicio" como `as initial View controller` me salta el error.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Os dejo el código de mi ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import MBCircularProgressBar
import MessageUI
import SafariServices
import Pods_Interlight_App



class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    
    var sensor = [Sensores]()

    
    
    // OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS OUTLETS
    
        //Menu Principal
    @IBOutlet weak var marbellaMenuOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoMenuOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var urlMenuOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playMenuOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mensajeMenuOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var facebookMenuOutlet: UIButton!
    
    
            //Menu - Marbella
        @IBOutlet weak var entornoMairenaOutlet: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var vistaMairenaOutlet: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var infoMairenaOutlet: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var urlMairenaOutlet: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var playMairenaOutlet: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var mensajeMairenaOutlet: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var facebookMairenaOutlet: UIImageView!
    
                //Parametros entorno - Marbella
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaTemp: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaHum: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaPres: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaIlu: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaPlu: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaSono: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaIUV: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaUVA: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet var entornoMarbellaPEA: MBCircularProgressBarView!
            @IBOutlet weak var entornoMarbellaInfo: UIButton!
            @IBOutlet weak var entornoMarbellaUrl: UIButton!
            @IBOutlet weak var entornoMarbellaPlay: UIButton!
            @IBOutlet weak var entornoMarbellaMensaje: UIButton!
            @IBOutlet weak var entornoMarbellaFacebook: UIButton!
    
                //Vista - Marbella
    @IBOutlet weak var vistaMarbellaVideo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var vistaMarbellaLocalizacion: UIButton!
    
    
                //Info - Marbella
            @IBOutlet weak var infoMarbellaInfo: UIButton!
    
    
    //MENSAJE
    @IBOutlet weak var mensajeOutlet: UIButton!
    
    
    
    
    
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        //FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES FUNCIONES

            // Funcion que trata de recoger los datos y agregarlos a un array -> getData()
           
            SensoresRequest().getData { result in
                switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    case .success(let sensores):
                        self.sensor.append(sensores[0])
                       // print(sensor.id, sensor.userId, sensor.body, sensor.title)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            if self.sensor.count > 0 {
                                guard let senA = self.sensor[0].sensorA else {return}
                                guard let senB = self.sensor[0].sensorB else {return}
                                guard let senC = self.sensor[0].sensorC else {return}
                                guard let senD = self.sensor[0].sensorD else {return}
                                guard let senE = self.sensor[0].sensorE else {return}
                                guard let senK = self.sensor[0].sensorK else {return}
                                guard let senM = self.sensor[0].sensorM else {return}
                                guard let senN = self.sensor[0].sensorN else {return}
                                guard let senJ = self.sensor[0].sensorJ else {return}
                           
                    
                        
                                //CONVIERTO EL STRING A NSNUMBER Y DE NSNUMBER A CGFLOAT
                                guard let tem = NumberFormatter().number(from: senA) else { return }
                                var floatTem = CGFloat(truncating: tem)
                                print(floatTem)
                                
                                guard let hum = NumberFormatter().number(from: senB) else { return }
                                var floatHum = CGFloat(truncating: hum)
                                print(floatHum)
                                
                                guard let atm = NumberFormatter().number(from: senC) else { return }
                                var floatAtm = CGFloat(truncating: atm)
                                
                                guard let ilu = NumberFormatter().number(from: senD) else { return }
                                var floatIlu = CGFloat(truncating: ilu)
                                
                                guard let plu = NumberFormatter().number(from: senE) else { return }
                                var floatPlu = CGFloat(truncating: plu)
                                
                                guard let uva = NumberFormatter().number(from: senK) else { return }
                                var floatUva = CGFloat(truncating: uva)
                                
                                guard let iuv = NumberFormatter().number(from: senM) else { return }
                                var floatIuv = CGFloat(truncating: iuv)
                                
                                guard let pea = NumberFormatter().number(from: senN) else { return }
                                var floatPea = CGFloat(truncating: pea)
                                
                                guard let son = NumberFormatter().number(from: senJ) else { return }
                                var floatSon = CGFloat(truncating: son)
                               
                           
                                    //CONVIERTO EL NSNUMBER A CGFLOAT
                              
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0) {
                                        
                                        self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "Calor Nivel III")
                                        if floatTem <= 0 {
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor.white
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.value = floatTem
                                        }
                                        if floatTem >= 1 && floatTem <= 9 {
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "Frio Nivel II")
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.value = floatTem
                                        }
                                        if floatTem <= 10 && floatTem <= 19 {
                                            
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "Frio Nivel I")
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.value = floatTem
                                        }
                                        if floatTem <= 20 && floatTem <= 29 {
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "T. Confort")
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.value = floatTem
                                        }
                                        if floatTem <= 30 && floatTem <= 36 {
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "Calor Nivel I")
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.value = floatTem
                                        }
                                        if floatTem <= 37 && floatTem <= 45 {
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "Calor Nivel II")
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.value = floatTem
                                        }
                                        if floatTem >= 46 {
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "Calor Nivel III")
                                            self.entornoMarbellaTemp.value = floatTem
                                        }
                                    }

                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaHum.maxValue = 100
                                        self.entornoMarbellaHum.value = floatHum
                                    }
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaPres.value = floatAtm
                                    }
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaIlu.value = floatIlu
                                    }
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaPlu.value = floatPlu
                                    }
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaUVA.value = floatUva
                                    }
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaIUV.value = floatIuv
                                    }
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaPEA.value = floatPea
                                    }
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                                        self.entornoMarbellaSono.value = floatSon
                                    }
                           
                             
                                
                               
                                
                                //self.labelOutlet.text = senA
                               // self.labelOutlet.text = "\(intsenB)"

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        
            

    
   
    }
    
  //EMAIL
    
        //Funcion que realiza un email
    @objc private func didTapButton() {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let vc = MFMailComposeViewController()
            vc.delegate = self
            vc.setSubject("Contacta con nosotros!")
            vc.setToRecipients(["info@interlight.es"])
            vc.setMessageBody("Escribe aquí tu mensaje", isHTML: true)
            
            present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc), animated: true)
        }
        else {
            guard let url2 = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") else {
                return
            }
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url:url2)
            present(vc, animated: true)
        }
      
    }
        
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
        //Funcion error para la realizacion del email
        
     /*   func showMailError() {
            let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "No se pudo realizar el email", message: "Tu dispositivo no pudo realizar el email", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
            self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } */
    
    
    
    
    
    //Funcion que busca en youtube el video de Interlight
    
    func searchYoutube() {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NJYKQ7BtZU")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    
    }
    
    //Funcion que te lleva a Interlight.es
    
    func searchInterlight() {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.interlight.es")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    
    }
    
    //Funcion que te lleva al Facebook de Interlight
    
    func searchFacebook() {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/Interlight_sp-520127731413677/?hc_ref=ARQ1-43_u5m1sevDE6s87dmdSOZNiab32FhvQEh8KuL5cJEE3dNZlHK8T3ozg3JVK4Y&fref=nf&__xts__[0]=68.ARBxELqHjSTSwftlWR6QKDsQPq_G2dfHdk9mdYnyWcOR4m0PYnjOMNxVbNI7EoC2ugOfYXf6tfcKI4oAfVyl5Jc7LSchzj3keWZ_SM7DlXbpvn1w2lIK0etKm4eGNRd6RTGf7XoTUAzeqWiWBWoaXOrhMrKK_hcka5IR9dZOeH3WdIu87TbaZ3DFti5-HG4hOfoBfeauOaxjZGS2bR1Ei0im7CPZzYiW1ydekyGEMbA-lmwb4FxbIbi0OCIUi7MA20GTAsJSBn2L4lm2-gMPtbE-eg25b4nx4Xxyo0zWlfMg8xVCfNxlP8HgzV215u9mfukzrP4RsCaZIldm1OLATDrAHbxEYqLo-syfWwBwtC-btlQF0EYe08FK6UbfW3Jnq6lDTkO1mK9m4xEC4u3pVxnxH3aioZm39N0mjpy4u4GBGHewohjdcMLf_6Yw9mcpPr1rSYlB7TTepTMQfb52kVdD2Md-SLx3s2jxJ9C4F4NEcuI2B06uaPitFh-wMqx9bQ&__tn__=kC-R")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    
    }
    
    //Funcion que busca el google maps la dirección de la calle de Marbella
    func searchMaps() {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.es/maps/place/36°30'53.8%22N+4°53'21.1%22W/@36.5149444,-4.8913831,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d36.514944!4d-4.889194")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    
    
    // ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS ACTIONS
    
    
    
    
    // MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU
    
    
    // Menu -> Actions
    
    
    @IBAction func marbellaMenuBoton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func infoMenu(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func urlMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        searchInterlight()
    }
    
    @IBAction func playMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        searchYoutube()
    }
    
    @IBAction func mensajeMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        didTapButton()
    }
    
    @IBAction func facebookMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        searchFacebook()
    }
    
    
    // MARBELLA MARBELLA MARBELLA MARBELLA MARBELLA MARBELLA MARBELLA MARBELLA MARBELLA
    
    
            //Marbella - Miraflores -> Actions
        
        @IBAction func marbellaEntorno(_ sender: Any) {
        }
        
        @IBAction func marbellaVista(_ sender: Any) {
        }
        
        @IBAction func marbellaInfo(_ sender: Any) {
        }
        
        @IBAction func marbellaUrl(_ sender: Any) {
            searchInterlight()
        }
        
        @IBAction func marbellaPlay(_ sender: Any) {
            searchYoutube()
        }
        
        @IBAction func marbellaMensaje(_ sender: Any) {
        }
        
        @IBAction func marbellaFacebook(_ sender: Any) {
            searchFacebook()
        }
    
    
    
    
            //Marbella - Miraflores - PARÁMETROS DE ENTORNO
    
    @IBAction func entornoMarbellaUrl(_ sender: Any) {
        searchInterlight()
    }
    @IBAction func entornoMarbellaPlay(_ sender: Any) {
        searchYoutube()
    }
    @IBAction func entornoMarbellaFacebook(_ sender: Any) {
        searchFacebook()
    }
    
    
            //Marbella - Miraflores - VISTA DE PROYECTO
    @IBAction func vistaMarbellaVideo(_ sender: Any) {
        searchYoutube()
    }
    @IBAction func vistaMarbellaLocalizacion(_ sender: Any) {
        searchMaps()
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    //MENSAJE
    @IBAction func mensajeBoton(_ sender: Any) {
        
    }
    
  
}
```

La pantalla donde pone Bienvenido es la pantalla de inicio y la pantalla donde veis el recuadro negro es la pantalla de representación de los gauges.

Y Aquí la imagen de mi Storyboard.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es la línea 139?

Comment: La línea en la cual empiezo a tocar los gauges -> self.entornoMarbellaTemp.progressColor = UIColor(named: "Calor Nivel III")

Comment: Tengo que recalcar que los datos que estoy utilizando los recojo de MySQL con una API Rest (en php) la cual codifica dichos datos en JSON. Dichos datos los descodifico en otro .swift de forma Decodable y luego los agrego a un array interno para luego convertirlos en NSNumber y posteriormente a CGFloat. Recalco que puedo corregir el error si a la ventana de los gauges lo marco como "as initial view controller", pero no puedo utilizarla como tal ya que tengo otra ventana la cual actúa como ventana inicial (que es la ventana de la foto, la que pone Bienvenido en la parte TOP) .

Comment: Creo que puede ser por el ciclo de vida de la app. Soy novato en swift así que solo puedo decir esto hasta el momento.

Comment: Respondiendo a tú pregunta Bicho: El error me sale porque encuentro un nil cuando llega a esa línea, lo cual me parece muy raro ya que el dato lo imprimo anteriormente y me sale correcto.

Comment: Dejando de lado los Gauges y representando el dato en un Label todo está correcto, el error viene cuando intento utilizar los Gauges y representar mis variables en ellos,

Comment: Ahora intenta lo mismo pero agregando el color y con el if, sin utilizar UIView.animate. Si funciona entonces esa animación es la que algo tiene

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de solucionarlo!

Para empezar tenía todas mis pantallas asignadas al ViewController.swift. Por tanto, he creado otro "ViewController" al que lo he llamado "ViewController2" y he asignado la pantalla de mis Gauges al ViewController2. Ahora se ven todos los datos representados sin ningún problema!